Can we think that any multi-qubit quantum gate has a constant complexity from physics perspective?
It's known that any multi-qubit quantum gate can be represented as a product of a number of CNOT and single-qubit gates. The total number of these simple gates required is exponential (in the number of qubits) on average, and thus we can say that an average complexity for a random gate is exponential. Thus, there can be a big difference between some two multi-qubit gates. But this is just from one perspective.
In reality a quantum gate is a physical device. Why, from physics perspective, one quantum gate should be more complex than another one?
As an analogy, think of the distinction between classical CPU and specialized hardware, like FPGA, ASIC, GPU, TPU, LPU, etc. Specialized hardware is much faster for specific tasks, while they are not supposed to be universal computing devices like CPUs.
So, would it be possible for a random quantum gate to physically construct a device that will compute it with a speed comparable to, say, the computation of the Walsh-Hadamard gate?
Perhaps, this question sounds more reasonable when we have just one quantum system with $d$ degrees of freedom and look for a complexity of a random unitary acting on it.

What is your definition of universal when you say "while they are not universal computing devices like CPUs"?

@MarkSpinelli They aren't supposed to realize any possible computation, just specific ones (sure, usually you can emulate others too, but with penalty costs).

For a quantum device in question I'd be happy if it could implement just a single unitary.

Great question. I suppose one might make arguments about the kind of (Hamiltonian) interactions needed to build a specific gate, and the complexity (ie in terms of required time-control) of the corresponding dynamic. Eg, could one possibly argue that any gate that is implementable using only two-qubit interactions with constant Hamiltonian is equally "simple"? Of course, that would assume experimental control capable of setting those specific interaction strengths precisely enough. Eg things like the Toffoli can be implemented in such a way. Does that make them "as simple" as 2-qubit gates?


Why, from physics perspective, one quantum gate should be more complex than another one?

The average gate has to be extremely complex to implement, because there are so many possible gates. Consider that there are 31446995505814020383166371418359014222725120000 different 8-qubit Clifford gates. Every one of those gates will require a different implementation. The implementation strategy needs to have enough details that you can encode that many differences, and this inherently makes the implementation strategy complex. But then there will be outlier gates, like single qubit rotations, that we see in practice are much easier than this.
In order for all gates to have the same cost, it would need to be the case that the easiest gate to implement was as hard as the average gate. But the average gate is necessarily totally miserable to implement, and the easiest gates just don't look like that. There are approximately $10^{150000}$ thousand-qubit stabilizer states. So to prepare the average stability state you'd need hundreds of thousands of knobs you can twiddle, just to ensure you have enough degrees of freedom to specify them all. On the other hand, one of those states is "each qubit in the $|0\rangle$ state", which you can prepare by just waiting a millisecond for all the qubits to T1 decay into the $|0\rangle$ state. It's very hard to not have outliers that are easy.
More generally, the gate you're trying to perform can look more/less like physics. For example, physics is local and the gate may also be local; that'll make it easier to do. Physics is mostly built out of two-body interactions, so if the gate only requires interactions between pairs of qubits instead of all-to-all interactions, the gate will be easier to do. Etc.

Thanks, I understand that. I'd say this is a classical perspective, because we assume that a quantum computation is a sequence of simpler quantum computations. However, more abstractly, a quantum state evolves by some physical process. It doesn't have to be a computation on a gate-based quantum computer, it could be some alternative physical process, such as adiabatic computation, or something else, entirely different. The question is closer to "Can we separate complexity of quantum physical processes on some fundamental physical level?" I guess it's in the vicinity of quantum field theories.

(too long for a comment)
I'm trying to analogize this question to other, classical things that I know about. For example, in the early days of (classical) integrated circuit computing we had resistor-diode logic - which was not universal at least because we were limited to AND and OR gates. So we upgraded to resistor-transistor logic (RTL) initially using NPN (or PNP) bipolar transistors; this was succeeded by diode-transistor, then transistor-transistor, and finally complimentary metal-oxide transistor technology used in the majority of classical processors nowadays.
CMOS has an advantage because, for example, a two-input NAND gate can be realized with "just" four transistors. But a two-input XOR gate needs eight such transistors. While a three-input "AND-OR-INVERT" gate can be realized with fewer than the naive guess of ten such transistors.
But (classical) computer engineers will just take it as they come - we don't ponder too much why the AOI gate is less complex than the XOR gate (but we want to use AOI gates where we can, for efficiency purposes...)

The question is closer to analog computing rather than classical digital, I suppose. It's hard to define complexity of analog computation other than as the time passed since the start of a computation.

@DanyloY Making the computer analog doesn't change the difficulty. The average gate must be hard, by counting/weighing the sheer number of possible operations and considering how many knobs you'd need and how precise they'd have to be, but in practice certain gates are much easier than that, therefore not all gates are the same cost.
